# Multiple image swap - Unsure where to begin

Tags: javascript, image, mouseover, swap

I'm working on an image swap (I'm fairly inexperienced with JavaScript), and I'm not sure where to begin. Here's what I'm trying to work with and what I'm trying to do:

One default image.

Five pre-loaded images.

Five text links with mouseover behaviors that will swap a pre-loaded image for the default image OR one of the previously displayed rollover images. All images would be in the same location on the page.

One text link that reloads the default image.

Whichever new image that's displayed would - ideally but not required - be persistent until the next image is loaded (pre-loaded image or default image).

Hopefully I'm explaining this clearly. I'm better at modifying JavaScript than I am starting from scratch. In the interest of learning, I'm not necessarily looking for a fully-developed script, but if someone could give me a nudge in the right direction I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found the solution. Here's the final version of what I found and modified...

```
<script>
function changeimage(towhat,url){
if (document.images){
document.images.targetimage.src=towhat.src
gotolink=url
}
}
function warp(){
window.location=gotolink
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
var myimages=new Array()
var gotolink="#"

function preloadimages(){
for (i=0;i<preloadimages.arguments.length;i++){
myimages[i]=new Image()
myimages[i].src=preloadimages.arguments[i]
}
}
preloadimages("1a.png","2a.png","3a.png","4a.png","5a.png","red.png")
</script>

<!---->

<a href="javascript:warp()"><img src="red.png" name="targetimage" border=0 height="40" width="40"></a>
<br>
<a href="#" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[0],this.href)">11111</a> <!-- image 1 -->
<br>
<a href="#" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[1],this.href)">22222</a> <!-- image 2 -->
<br>
<a href="#" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[2],this.href)">33333</a> <!-- image 3 -->
<br>
<a href="#" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[3],this.href)">44444</a> <!-- image 4 -->
<br>
<a href="#" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[4],this.href)">55555</a> <!-- image 5 -->
<br>
<a href="#" onMouseover="changeimage(myimages[5],this.href)">RRRRR</a> <!-- default image -->
```